# Caliburn allow only one Window of a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn

I have a ViewModel, which is launched from my MainViewModel.
Unfortunately, only one Instance of this Window is useful. Ideally another click on the button should simply reactive the window.

I saw a reference to the Caliburn Property "IsActive" on the ViewModel, but my Caliburn.Micro Project does not contain this Property.

Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT:

```
public void BtnShowLog()
{
   this.windowManager.ShowWindow(new LogViewModel(this.windowManager));
}
```

This button shows my LogViewModel. Basically: If there is an instance of the LogViewmodel, it should abort.

Comment: Oo - Can you describe it a bit more? I don't have a clue what you're talking about. How about some code?

Comment: Sorry, I did not provide any code because the problem is so generic. I added the my button code

Comment: Hmm...sorry, I've to ask again. What's your point? Do you want to reuse the view with another VM or do you want to reuse the VM with another view?

Comment: @DHN No, I do not want to reuse the view. The View should only be used once.